# composer connection refused

Tags: magento2, composer

## Context:

- magento 2.1.7 community-edition
- composer.phar 1.7.2
- installed and setup on a development server
- then deployed on a production server (dictinct from the previous)

All worked well, including frontend, products, orders, invoice... but we now required to update magento (at least 2.2.0):

- `~/.composer/auth.json` set up.
- /home/web/www-preprod is magento root directory (and where composer.json and composer.phar resides)
- composer.phar similar to the one used on the development server

## Attempt 1: wizard

Stuck at "readiness check":

> Check component Dependency
>    We found conflicting component dependencies

## Attempt 2: CLI

Stuck at any `composer update` or `composer require`

`php composer.phar update`

> Loading composer repositories with package information
>   
>   [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
>   
>   The "https://repo.magento.com/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: failed to open stream: Connection refused
>
> update [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--lock] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--no-suggest] [--with-dependencies] [--with-all-dependencies] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [-i|--interactive] [--root-reqs] [--] []...

---

## Diagnose

```
$ php composer.phar diagnose ; echo 'done'; grep wait
```

> Checking composer.json: WARNING
>   
> The version field is present, it is recommended to leave it out if the package is published on Packagist.
>   
> Defining autoload.psr-0 with an empty namespace prefix is a bad idea for performance
>   
> require.magento/product-community-edition : exact version constraints (2.1.7) should be avoided if the package follows semantic versioning
>   
> require.composer/composer : unbound version constraints (@alpha) should be avoided
>   
> Checking platform settings: WARNING
>   
> PHP was compiled with --enable-sigchild which can cause issues on some platforms.
>   
> Recompile it without this flag if possible, see also:
>   
>   https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=22999
>   
>   
> Checking git settings: OK
>   
> Checking http connectivity to packagist: WARNING
>   
> [Composer\Downloader\TransportException] The "http://repo.packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: failed to open stream: Connection refused
>   
> Checking https connectivity to packagist: WARNING
>   
> [Composer\Downloader\TransportException] The "https://repo.packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: failed to open stream: Connection refused
>   
> Checking github.com rate limit: OK
>   
> Checking disk free space: OK
>   
> Checking pubkeys: Tags Public Key Fingerprint: * Dev Public Key Fingerprint: * OK
>   
> Checking composer version: WARNING
>   
> You are not running the latest stable version, run `composer self-update` to update (1.7.2 => 1.8.0)
>   
> Composer version: 1.7.2
>   
> PHP version: 7.0.32
>   
> PHP binary path: /usr/local/php7.0/bin/php

The server cannot reach repo.packagist.org/packages.json through neither http nor https

## update -vvv

> $ php -f composer.phar update -vvv ; echo 'done'; grep wait
>   
> Reading ./composer.json
>   
> Loading config file /home/me/.composer/config.json
>   
> Loading config file /home/me/.composer/auth.json
>   
> Loading config file ./composer.json
>   
> Checked CA file /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt: valid
>   
> Failed to initialize global composer: Composer could not find the config file: /home/me/.composer/composer.json
>   
> To initialize a project, please create a composer.json file as described in the https://getcomposer.org/ "Getting Started" section
>   
> Reading /home/web/www-preprod/vendor/composer/installed.json
>   
> Loading plugin MagentoHackathon\Composer\Magento\Plugin
>   
> activate magento plugin
>   
> Running 1.7.2 (2018-08-16 16:57:12) with PHP 7.0.32 on Linux / 4.14.66-ovh-vps-grsec-zfs-classid
>   
> Loading composer repositories with package information
>   
> Downloading https://repo.magento.com/packages.json
>   
> Downloading https://repo.magento.com/packages.json
>   
> Downloading https://repo.magento.com/packages.json
>   
>   
>   [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
>   
>   The "https://repo.magento.com/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: failed to open stream: Connection refused
>   
>   
> Exception trace:
>   
>  () at phar:///home/web/www-preprod/composer.phar/src/Composer/Util/RemoteFilesystem.php:547
>   
>  Composer\Util\RemoteFilesystem->get() at phar:///home/web/www-preprod/composer.phar/src/Composer/Util/RemoteFilesystem.php:101
>   
>  Composer\Util\RemoteFilesystem->getContents() at phar:///home/web/www-preprod/composer.phar/src/Composer/Repository/ComposerRepository.php:682
>   
>  [... skip some lines for readability ...]
>   
>  Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at phar:///home/web/www-preprod/composer.phar/src/Composer/Console/Application.php:103
>   
>  Composer\Console\Application->run() at phar:///home/web/www-preprod/composer.phar/bin/composer:56
>   
>  require() at /home/web/www-preprod/composer.phar:24
>   
>  
>   
>  [...]

Lacking of any credentials, proxy or configuration error: did anyone had this error too? Googling did not show that specific error.

## EDIT: Clue: auth.json

Following @sebastian 's comment, to be thorough:

1. I renamed my /home/me/.composer/auth.json.and
2. ran `composer.phar global config http-basic.repo.magento.com <public_key> 
   <private_key>` to be sure
3. that command regenerates the file in /home/me/.composer/
4. retrying composer update the very same errors pops up (same stack with -vvv).

Other test: Even without any auth.json, the composer update -vvv ends up identical.

My best clue so far is a server limitation (blacklisted?), I am looking for:
 - a solution to run composer update on local .json (since I can wget them)
 - getting back the magento 2.1.7 on dev server, upgrading it from there and then re-uploading on prod server

### EDIT: Follow-up on local .json

I managed to set composer.json repository to local:

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "path",
        "url": "/home/web/www-preprod/packages.json"
    }
],
```

Composer update output:

> Problem 1
>   
>     - The requested package magento/product-community-edition 2.2.0 exists as magento/product-community-edition[2.1.7] but these are rejected by your constraint.

---

New attempt: set up composer.json by CLI

```
php composer.phar require magento/community-edition 2.2.0 --no-update
```

> ./composer.json has been updated

```
php composer.phar update
```

> Loading composer repositories with package information
>   
> The "https://repo.packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: failed to open stream: Connection refused
>   
> https://repo.packagist.org could not be fully loaded, package information was loaded from the local cache and may be out of date
>   
> Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
>   
>   
>  [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
>   
>   The "http://repo.packagist.org/p/ramsey/uuid%247189d3afa8232bcec2b8a64e5043b64b57616fd03b0280bd3e9995f5c32d50f8.json" file could not be downloaded: failed to
>   
>  open stream: Connection refused
>   
>  [...]

So... Now, how to get and setup local .json from repo.packagist.org?

Comment: Exploring https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52404280/laravel-composer-update-connection-refused (the production server may have that kind of quirks). If that's the case, it is more a composer vs. network parameters than a magento-related issue

Comment: After several weeks, the problem is still there. In the meantime, we redeployed a copy updated on our computers.

Answer (score 0):

u've added

`...
"repo.magento.com": {
    "username": "<YOUR-MAGENTO-PUBLIC-KEY>",
    "password": "<YOUR-MAGENTO-PRIVATE-KEY>"
}
...`

to your `~/.composer/auth.json`, right?

Your log tells me that the connection is refused for https://repo.**magento.com**/packages.json and not only repo.**packagist.org**/packages.json

> The "https://repo.magento.com/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: failed to open stream: Connection refused

Have you tried to put the auth.json into the Mage dir or the http-auth credentials directly into composer.json?

What is the current work dir you're calling `php composer.phar update` ?

Comment: Hi sebastian, thanks for the advice, I edited the post: no success with the auth.json clue.

Comment: @nicolallias ok, have you tried a simple curl for that package [http://repo.packagist.org/p/ramsey/uuid..json](http://repo.packagist.org/p/ramsey/uuid%247189d3afa8232bcec2b8a64e5043b64b57616fd03b0280bd3e9995f5c32d50f8.json) ? Setting up a packagist proxy may work with [toran](https://toranproxy.com/) or satis.. but i don't think thats ur problem. Looks like there is a misconfiguration in composer.. What file do you mean with: /home/me/.composer/

Comment: /home/me is the home folder of my unix user. /home/me/.composer is COMPOSER_HOME ; I indeed to plan to wget (or curl) every required files... I will keep you in touch ;)

Comment: Maybe you can show the content of your /home/me/.composer/auth.json and /home/me/.composer/composer.json? I'm confused about that u've got content in the /home/me/.composer/composer.json? :-D I would probably backup both files in /home/me/.composer, delete them, put the auth.json into Mage Root and do a fresh install by composer install (via composer.lock) not composer update. On prod environments i usallly use the --prefer-dist option for composer install

Comment: composer.json is in magento root directory (/home/web/www-preprod/), in which I launch every `php -f composer.phar` commands

Comment: composer.json: https://pastebin.com/NvMWZKCU (customized to parse local packages.json, which I got from `wget https://repo.magento.com/packages.json`)

Comment: Have you tried these fixed mentied in the github issue [https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/4388](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/4388) ? What happens if you update composer to 1.8.2, remove composer cache and vendor dir (maybe the composer.lock too) and do a fresh install with composer install?

Comment: I understand, but I am using v1.7.2 of composer, my error message "failed to open stream: Connection refused" is inconsistent with all of theirs... I wait for the resolution of the incident ticket on the host company behalf. In the meanwhile, I duplicate the production website on another server (which has no restrictions), attempting to upgrade there and later re-upload on the production server.